# I'm trying to understand How a sequence of fork() function work?

Tags: c++, fork

I'm trying to understand how the below sequence of fork() functions work?

```
                #include <iostream>
                #include <sys/types.h>
                #include <unistd.h>
                using namespace std;
                int main() {
                  fork();   cout << "1 "  << endl;//calling fork 1
                  fork();   cout << "2 " << endl; // calling fork 2
                  fork();   cout << "3 "  << endl;// calling fork 3

                  fork();   cout<<" 4 "<<endl;//calling fork 4
                  return 0;
                }
```

1. will my process structure for above program look like this,Is my assumption correct?

   ```
                                    parent(x)
                                   /       |     |   \
                                  1        2     3    4
                              /   |  \    / \    |
                             2    3   4  3   4   4
                            / \   |      |
                           3   4  4      4
                           |
                           4
   ```

   - As per my understanding the program will generate 16 processes am I right?
   - Is it possible to output 3 before 2? if so How and why?

Comment: For the last question, just because a new process is created it doesn't have to start running immediately. The parent process can still run, and since you have multiple other processes one of them could easily print 2 and 3 before some other process prints 2.

Comment: Oh and please don't use multiple language tags unless you are comparing features of the languages you tag. Only use the language you're actually programming in (C++ for this example).

Comment: In the tree what do the numbers represent?
Each each node is a process?

Also if this helps 1 will be printed two 2 times. 2 will be printed 4 times, 3 -> 8, 4->16

And the program will generate 15 new processes + 1 for the program invocation you make.

Comment: It is possible for one process to output 3 before another outputs 2. It is not possible for one particular process to output 3 before 2. You could also print the pid (look for the getpid function) before the number. PS: An easy way to count the number of processes in the end is to comment first three couts.

Comment: @Some programmer dude thanks for the explanation as well as  suggestion regarding the tags will surely follow from my next posts.

Comment: @user183833 thanks for making it clear how the processes will be generated

Comment: @Fernando Coelho thank you for making it more clear

Comment: You have the perfect opportunity to just try it out and let it run a few times. Have you tried that? You just need to give every fork its own id and print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding the program will generate 16 processes am I right?

The first process will fork off a new process. That's one. There are now two processes running.

The two processes will then, as a result of the second fork, create two more processes. There are now four processes running.

The next fork results in eight running processes.

The last fork results in sixteen processes running. That's fifteen more than you started with, so, overall, the forks created fifteen new processes.

> Is it possible to output 3 before 2? if so How and why?

Yes, it's possible in the sense that it could happen, from a very isolated viewpoint. A 3 will never appear before the first 2, but it's possible that a 3 could be followed by a 2.

In order to print a "3", a "2" must be printed. There is no execution path that will print "3" before a "2" for a single process.

But:

```
fork();   cout << "2 " << endl;
```

There are four processes running after this fork. There is nothing that guarantees that all of them will print a "2" before they, or their descendants, all print their "3".

One of the four processes could, for example, be bumped down in priority by the operating system, and doesn't get to its `cout << "2"` until the other three processes printed their 2s, forked, and printed their 3s. Now, the sleeping process wakes up and prints its "2", after the other processes already blurted out their "3"s. End result will be a "3" followed by a "2".

But there must be other "2"s before any of those "3"s.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding the program will generate 16 processes am I right?

There will be 16 processes in total. When the program is run, 15 more processes will be generated as a consequence of the calls to `fork()`.

> Is it possible to output 3 before 2? if so How and why?

I don't think so. The standard library functions don't give you control over sequencing the output of forked processes to `stdout`. Hence, they are written to `stdout` in an order that cannot be controlled by a program.

Comment: As I stated in a comment and to be pedant (sorry :P) the program will generate 15 new processes and one extra will be the process that the user invoked.

Comment: @user183833, fair enough.